# "Standard" way of creating config file suitable for Python and Java together

Tags: java, python, config

My application was 100% developed in pure Python. I found very useful and easy to create a config file with `.py` extension and than simply load it in every code. Something like this:

```
ENV = 'Dev'
def get_settings():
    return eval(ENV)

class Dev():
    ''' Development Settings '''

    # AWS settings
    aws_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    aws_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    # S3 settings
    s3_bucket = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    ...
    ...
```

And than in my code I just import this file and use settings, this way I have one file that easy to manage and that contains all aprameters I need.

Howewer recently I had to move part of my code to Java. And now I'm struggling with configurations.

### Question:

What are the "standard"  way to create a config that would be easily accessible from both languages? (My Java skills are very limited, if you can five me a brief example in Java it would be great)

Comment: i would suggest XML or JSON

Comment: Use standard configuration files like `XML`, `.properties`. Both languages have libraries to parse them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) in Python

The syntax on this file looks like this:

```
[Section]
my_option = 12.2
my_option2 = other_value

[Section2]
my_voption = my_value
```

You read it this way:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.cfg')
config.getfloat('Section', 'my_option') # returns 12.2
```

It works for a couple of types and if you can't find a type, you can use the `eval` function in Python. Finding an equivalent to Java shouldn't be too hard. Or even parsing this file using Java shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard configuration files : XML or .properties for example.

For XML, you can use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) in Java, [minidom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) in Python.

For .properties, Java handles this nativaly via class [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and Python can handle this via [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)